# Replace text in a string exclude anchor text

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I would like to search words in string and want to replace first occurrence in that string. Also i would like to exclude text which is between  Tag  only. Which means text which has hyper link should not be replace.

This should check new line in new line.

**Example:**

> Here is < a > my < / a > String. I Would like to replace my string. In
>   this string only 1 my will be replace which is first and doesn't has
>   anchor link.

Replace my with "This"

**Output.**

> Here is < a > my < / a > String. I would like to replace this string.
>   In this string only 1 my will be replace which is first and doesn't
>   has anchor link.

Thanks

Comment: *only 1 **my** will* does not replaced with **this**?

Comment: Means First occurrence of the find word will be only replaced. Like in my example I have three my. So first my is an hyper link so need to exclude and then second my will replace with the string . so 3rd my will keep remain as the original one.

Comment: Use `preg_replace('/(?<!< a >)my(?!< \/a >)/', 'this', $string, 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match the first occurrence of "my" which is not contained in `<a> </a>` tag only.

```
^.*?\Kmy(?![^>]*\/\s*a\s*>)
```

and replace it with "this" as you want in your post.

**Explanation:**

- `^` --> Start of input
- `.*?` --> Match any characters in non-greedy way (to capture first occurencce of my)
- `\K` --> Reset whatever matched so only "my" gets matched which needs to be replace by "this"
- `(?![^>]*\/\s*a\s*>)` --> Negative look ahead to ensure "my" text is not contained in `<a> </a>` tag.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/t55e1k/2)

Here is a sample PHP code for same,

```
$str = 'Here is < a > my < / a > String. I Would like to replace my string. In this string only 1 my will be replace which is first and doesn\'t has anchor link.';
$res = preg_replace('/^.*?\Kmy(?![^>]*\/\s*a\s*>)/','this',$str);
echo $res;
```

This gives following output like you expect,

```
Here is < a > my < / a > String. I Would like to replace this string. In this string only 1 my will be replace which is first and doesn't has anchor link.
```

Comment: Thanks but in this regex it excludes all tag and i just want to exclude only < a > tag. and Also some time we have text in between () , {} like {MY} , (MY) so in this case this is not working. For example if we have <p> string </p> then this will not work.

Comment: In case you want to just avoid matching it for <a> </a> only, the regex can be easily modified to do same. And whether the text is in {} or () is already taken care. Updating my answer with new regex and demo. Let me know if you have any other case requirements.

Comment: Thank I have added \n in ignore list but not working. As above regex is failed to replace in new line. for example
$str = 'string which I needs to replace.
here is the new line which has EDR word which is not replaced. ' ;
$words_array = array(
 'which' => 'http://google.com',
 'EDR' => 'http://yahoo.com'
);

foreach($words_array as $word => $term_link){
 replacement = '<a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$word.'</a>';
 $str = preg_replace('/^.*?\K'.$word.'(?![^>]*\/\s*a\s*>)/',$replacement,$str);
 
}

Comment: If you want the match to happen in different lines too, you need to put (?s) in the very beginning of regex. So the updated regex becomes (?s)^.*?\Kmy(?![^>]*\/\s*a\s*>). Also, can you edit your post and put all requirements in your post? Asking through comments is not the right away.

Comment: Already Did that ('/(?s)^.*?\K'.$word.'(?![^>]*\/\s*a\s*>)/ Which is not working

Comment: Watch your parenthesis and slash, they doesn't seem to be written correctly. You need to write it like this /(?s)^.*?\Kmy(?![^>]*\/\s*a\s*>)/ Also you should edit your post and add more samples for what regex you are using with what input string and whats actual output vs expected output, so we can help you in a better way.

Comment: How can I do the same in golang regex, \K is not supported and second ? gives error "The preceding token is not quantifiable"